# Windows 10 upgrade with hyper-v missing "Local Area Connection - Virtual Network"

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Prior to the upgrade, I had Hyper-V running, and sharing the wired Ethernet adapter.

After the upgrade, all of the virtual adapters were disabled (and named "Network 2", "Network 3", ...). I could not re-enable them. The physical adapter was set as a Hyper-V virtual network switch, and the host OS could only connect to the network through a wireless adapter. I removed all the virtual adapters from the Device Manager, removed the Hyper-V virtual network switch driver via netcfg, and rebooted. The Virtual Network Switch driver was present after the reboot.

Now, when I try to create new virtual networks, I can't get the virtual adapter for my host OS--I can either use my Ethernet card for my host OS or a virtual one, but not both. I've tried checking the "share interface with management host" with a VM running and not running, but I don't get the virtual host adapter either way. (I've never had to work to get this set up before--it's always been automatic).

How can I set up the physical adapter to support multiple VMs and the management/host OS?  (Can I do this through PowerShell?)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Not sure why. I solved it by deleting the old virtual switch and creating a new one, which caused an enabled virtual network adapter to be created.